# How to publish messages on GCP PubSublite from Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Anybody already used GCP CredentialsControllerService and PublishGCPubSubLite processor from Apache Nifi?
I'm getting errors, and not found a concrete solution to Publish messages on Pub/Sub lite.

Note: GCP json keys are correct.

> Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Comment: Hi Everyone, I got the connection, by changing the authentication method. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can create your own answer, and even accept it. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Looks like that would be appreciated by at least one user. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yunnosch, Yeah, The solution i got is, add user_authorized key which contains the refresh token can make the connection between nifi and pubsublite.

```
"type": "authorized_user"
```